# What does $e^{\mu}$ mean for a measure $\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I have seen the notation $\int_M fe^{\mu}$ in some geometry books and I cannot even guess what $e^{\mu}$ might mean for a measure/form $\mu$ on the (symplectic) manifold $M$.

Any clarifications are appreciated.

**Edit**

Comment: Where did you see this notation?

Comment: @John I included an example from repn theory/symp geom.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emu

Comment: @JairTaylor what about Esigma?

Comment: My only thought is $e^\sigma = e^{(\sigma/\omega)} \omega$ for $\omega$ the canonical volume form, but I have never seen the notation before, nor studied symplectic geometry. Do none of the books define it?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I guess $\sigma$ is the symplectic $2$-form on $\Omega$ which is a symplectic manifold of dimension $2n$. Thus, $\frac{\sigma^n}{n!}$ is the Liouville volume form on $\Omega$. Perhaps $e^{\sigma}$ under the integration is just $\frac{\sigma^n}{n!}$ as $\frac{\sigma^k}{k!}=0$ for $k>n$. But I'm not really sure; it is not defined in any of the sources in which I have seen it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this remark in a book by Guillemin, Ginzburg, and Karshon:

> > It is convenient to work with the differential form (of mixed degree)
> >     $$\exp \omega=1+\omega+\frac{1}{2!}\omega\wedge\omega\dots .$$
> >     With the convention that $\int_M\beta=0$ if the degree of $\beta$ is different than the dimension of $M$, Liouville measure is given by integration of $\exp \omega$.

This shows that my guess in the above comments was correct! However, I would appreciate if an expert would clarify why it is "**convenient**" to work with this differential form of mixed degrees.

Comment: I guess because it's easier to write $e^\omega$ than $\frac{1}{7!} \omega\wedge\omega \wedge \dotsc \wedge\omega$. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't think writing $e^{\omega}$ is so much easier than $\omega^n/n!$ that justifies its use.

Comment: This remind me of Chern character http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class

Answer (score -2):

If $e^{\mu}=d\lambda$ for some measure $\lambda$ in $M$ then, it seems that  $\mu=\ln(d\lambda)$. But here is not clear whether $\ln(d\lambda)$ is a measure.